Calculating looped averages
I have a table containing dates within a single year and their corresponding average temperatures (mean_temp) for each day. My objective is to compute the average temperature for the next 30 days following each given date. However, I encountered difficulty in handling the last 30 observations.
So the data looks similar to this:
temp_data = tibble(
  day_year = c(1:366),
  temp = rnorm(366,5,2) 
  )

My initial attempt (below) resulted in either "error in temp_data$temp[1:(day_year - 335)]: ! only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts" or computing only one value for all last observations if i take absolute values of (day_year - 335).
temp_data |> 
  mutate(
    temp_next_30d = if_else(
      day_year < 336,
      rollapply(temp, width = 30, FUN = mean, align = "right", fill = NA, partial = TRUE),
      mean(temp_data$temp[day_year:366]) + mean(temp_data$temp[1:(day_year-335)])
    )
  )

Are there any elegant solutions to address this?

Welcome to SO.  Are you asking how to do this in code terms, or how you should approach the calculation conceptually?  If the latter, then this may not be the right site (cross-validated might be a better fit).  If the former - how would you calculate these means if you were doing it by hand?  Would you base it on the available data, attempt to extrapolate somehow, or leave them blank as having insufficient info?

If you're using partial=TRUE, then why bother with if_else?

The FALSE component of the if_else statement doesn't make any sense. You need to explain carefully what you want to do with the last 30 days.

@Edward from the way the if_else is written, I THINK the OP wants to loop the year - a day 15 before the end of the year takes an average of the 15 remaining days plus the first 15 days of the new year, but they have averaged each set separately then added them which seems not the best approach.

Welcome to SO, @AlexeyNosov. If you're going to use random numbers (rnorm), make sure to set.seed before for reproducibility's sake.

One option is to add the first 29 days to the data, calculate the rolling mean, and then remove those rows. And I think you want align='left`.
temp_data2 <- temp_data |> 
  bind_rows(slice(temp_data, 1:29)) |>
  mutate(
    temp_next_30d = zoo::rollapply(temp, width = 30, FUN = mean, 
                                   align = "left", fill = NA, partial = TRUE)) |>
  slice(1:366)


temp_data2
# A tibble: 366 × 3
   day_year  temp temp_next_30d
      <int> <dbl>         <dbl>
 1        1  4.30          4.51
 2        2  5.31          4.47
 3        3  6.04          4.37
 4        4  2.36          4.31
 5        5  3.83          4.44
 6        6  6.04          4.53
 7        7  4.48          4.50
 8        8  3.38          4.55
 9        9  5.04          4.71
10       10  4.30          4.72


tail(temp_data2)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  day_year  temp temp_next_30d
     <int> <dbl>         <dbl>
1      361  4.91          4.61
2      362  4.92          4.58
3      363  4.44          4.58
4      364  4.26          4.58
5      365  5.78          4.63
6      366  8.17          4.64


Yes, I was considering that approach too, but I was curious if there might be "cleaner" solutions available. Nevertheless, it indeed gets the job done. Thank you! (and apologies for the somewhat vague code earlier)
